# Create a bitmap at the first block of a char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, bitmap

Say, I have a char array in c++ with 64 blocks, each block has 64 bytes memory allocated:

```
char **disk = new char*[64];
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    disk[i] = new char[64];
}
```

And I want to set a bitmap in the the first block of the char array. 
The bitmap only contain integers.
So disk[0] should be the bitmap. The bitmap contains ether 1 for occupied, and 0 for free, specifying the rest of the blocks in array if they are occupied or free. 1 bit for per block.

But I don't know how to implement a bitmap for the specific size that I need becasue the bitmap should also be 64 bytes, and it include integers for 64 blocks, how can I achieve it?

This is the project requirement, so...I cannot define a bitmap outside of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hijacking what part of an array means, you should just make your own type:

```
struct MyType 
{
    bitmap_type bitmap;  // is this a uint64_t[8]? Or a std::bitset? Or... ?
    char data[63][64];   // or whatever dimensions
};

MyType* data = new MyType;
```

This way all the users of your type know that `data->bitmap` is the bitmap and `data->data` is the actual data, rather than having to remember that `data[0]` is special but `data[x]` for `x>0` is the actual data.

Comment: @Noah could always `reinterpret_cast` into `MyType` :)